# Sparkling Water: out of memory when converting spark dataframe to H2o dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, h2o, sparkling-water

I am trying to converting Spark DataFrame to H2O DataFrame

For spark setup, I am using

```
 .setMaster("local[1]")
 .set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
 .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
```

and I tried H2O 2.0.2 and H2O 1.6.4. I got both the same error at:

```
 val trainsetH2O: H2OFrame = trainsetH
 val testsetH2O: H2OFrame = testsetH
```

The error message is:

```
 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 49.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 62)
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
     at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
     at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
     at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
     at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:113)
     at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:331)
     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376)
     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493)
     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:602)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
```

where is wrong? The data in the trainset and testset are less than 10K, so it is actually pretty small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that you run out of PermGem memory which is not the same memory space as you usually configure for your driver and executors using

`.set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
.set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")`

This is part of JVM's memory which contains loaded classes. To increase it for both spark driver and executors, call `spark-submit` or `spark-shell` command with following arguments.

`--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:MaxPermSize=384m" --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:MaxPermSize=384m"`